# what is $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic to?

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to classify it using the fundamental homomorphism theorem. Any hints? Is this quotient a familiar group?

Comment: What type of "isomorphism" are you looking for? There is a general classification theorem for divisible groups, but the irreducible parts are the rationals and the Prufer $p$-groups. Since $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is totally torsion, it's clear that it has no $\mathbb{Q}$-parts. So, $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is going to be a direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}[p^\infty]$--is that really simpler?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. I think you're overestimating my experience.

Comment: What type of answer are you looking for? Give an example of what the type of isomorphism you want looks like.

Comment: Well, I want a "group isomorphism". I believe that specifies the "type of isomorphism". I have no idea how to answer the question of "how I'd want it to look like". I'd prefer if the answer used an approach which showed $\mathbb{Z}$ as being the kernel of some homomorphism.

Comment: I'm not sure you are going to find a pleasing answer to this question then. Do you have any reason to believe one exists?

Comment: http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=The_quotient_group_Q/Z

Comment: I guess my google searching skills suck.

Comment: If you only view them as additive group, then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1)$.

Comment: @SecretMath except that does not really make sense until you define a different addition on that set.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yea you are right. It is viewed as a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, not as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

For applying the "fundamental homomorphism theorem", one possibility is to consider the map
$f\colon \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, given by 
$$
\frac{a}{b}\rightarrow e^{\frac{2\pi i a}{b}}, 
$$
and then to compute the kernel and the image of $f$. As pointed out in the comments, this way the group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$, with $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ viewed as the torsion subgroup of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Whether this is more familiar than $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ itself I don't know.