# Is $\mathbb{R/Z}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q/Z}$?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

I’ve seen a proof that those quotient groups are isomorphic to the circle group, but I don’t know if they’re isomorphic to each other.
By transitivity, they should be, but I cannot prove it directly.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525581/what-is-mathbbq-mathbbz-isomorphic-to).

Comment: So the post says that $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ is isomorphic to $S^1$ but if $\mathbb{R/Z}$ is isomorphic to $S^1$ as well, why aren't $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ and $\mathbb{R/Z}$ isomorphic?

Comment: Because $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ is the torsion subgroup of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, so different from it. Where does it say that $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z\cong S^1$?

Comment: And what does that mean? I'm just a beginner in the subject, sorry.

Comment: Wait, so $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ is isomorphic to all of the $n$ th roots of unity, which is a subgroup of all the complex numbers $z$ where $|z|=1$ i.e. $S^1$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R/Z}$?

Comment: And it $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ is a torsion group because every element can be of the form $p/q + \mathbb{Z}$ and that element has order $q$, whereas $\mathbb{R/Z}$ has elements whose representatives are irrational numbers that have infinite order right?

Comment: We discussed this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993589/show-that-an-element-of-the-factor-group-mathbbr-mathbbz-has-finite-orde) yesterday.

Comment: You've cleared all my doubts; thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ has no infinite cyclic subgroup, whereas $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ does.

Answer (score 2):

A group-theoretic answer why they are not isomorphic is that $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is a *torsion* group, i.e. each element has a finite order. (The order of $p/q+\mathbb Z$ divides $q$.)

On the other side, some elements in $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ are of infinite order (e.g. $\sqrt{2}+\mathbb Z$).

Comment: @downvoter, I would like to improve my answer, if I could knew the reason for the downvote, please.

Answer (score 1):

They can't be isomorphic because they have different cardinalities. Indeed, note that
$$\mathbb{R} \to S^1: t \mapsto \exp(2 \pi it)$$
induces an isomorphism $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong S^1$, so $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is uncountable. On the other hand, $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is countable because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Comment: What about the homomorphism $f: \mathbb{Q/Z}→S^1 : q + \mathbb{Z} ↦ exp(2\pi q)$? Isn't it an isomorphism?

Comment: @LeonardoLovera An isomorphism must be surjective. The map you write  down is not surjective.

Comment: Give me a counterexample, please; I don't see it.

Comment: The image of your map is $\{\exp(2\pi i q)\mid q \in \mathbb{Q}\} \subsetneq S^1$. The problem is basically the same as asking if $\mathbb{Q}= \mathbb{R}$. You end up with a circle that has "points missing" in very much the same way as $\mathbb{Q}$ has holes missing.

Comment: So $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ is isomorphic to all of the $n$ th roots of unity, which is a subgroup of all the complex numbers $z$ where $|z|=1$ i.e. $S^1$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R/Z}$?

Comment: @LeonardoLovera Yes.